# How do I make my child theme's CSS update when I save it?

Tags: functions, css, child-theme

## Current System

- WordPress 4.1.1
- Theme: Child theme of [Lovecraft](https://wordpress.org/themes/lovecraft/)

## Issue Summary

My theme, a child theme of Lovecraft, is calling the stylesheet with the URI `[…]/blog/wp-content/themes/lovecraft-child/style.css?ver=4.1.1`. Note the `?ver=4.1.1`. When I edit `style.css` and upload the new version to my server, there is still a call to `style.css?ver=4.1.1` in the `<head>`, and my updates are not applied.

If I navigate to `style.css` in my browser, I see the new version with my updates. But my theme isn't calling that; it's calling `?ver=4.1.1`, which is not updating.

## functions.php (from child theme)

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css' );
}
```

What's keeping my child theme from taking the updates, and how do I resolve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFlare was caching my CSS files. I diagnosed this by selectively purging the CSS file from the cache, and then solved the issue by turning on "Development Mode", all via the CloudFlare dashboard.